# MonoDroid: Missing Button.SetText(span)

Tags: android, html, button, xamarin.android

I'm trying to set a Button's text with `Html.FromHtml("some html")` in `Mono for Android`.

In `Java` this works:

```
myButton.setText(Html.fromHtml("<small>(sub comment)</small>"));
```

But in Mono for Android that fails as there is `no signature` in `SetText` that accepts the `Html.FromHtml` span.

Is there another way this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Html.fromHtml()` returns `Spanned`, which extends `CharSequence` in both Android and MonoDroid.  But it appears that the Android `Button` class has a [`setText(CharSequence)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) method (from `TextView`), but the MonoDroid `Button` does not (not from [`TextView`](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.Widget.TextView/M) anyways).

It appears that there are other options that contain a `CharSequence` though, perhaps you could use one of those instead?

1. `TextView.SetText(Java.Lang.ICharSequence, TextView.BufferType)`
2. `TextView.set_TextFormatted(Java.Lang.ICharSequence)`
3. '`button.SetText(span, TextView.BufferType.Spannable);`

Answer (score 0):

The Java [TextView.setText(CharSequence)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) method is bound as the [TextView.Text](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aAndroid.Widget.TextView.Text) and [TextView.TextFormatted](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aAndroid.Widget.TextView.TextFormatted) properties:

```
myButton.TextFormatted = Html.FromHtml ("<small>(sub comment)</small>");
```